# Get Specific value instead of sum when parameters are multiple

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm creating a SSRS report of performance counter of 2 different tests. I want to show threshold of perf counter for both the test in report too.

When I'm selecting only 1 test then threshold value is proper.

[image]

I'm selecting 2 tests then it gives me sum of threshold for specific perf counter.

[image]

How do I get required data?

For this I've created 2 different Datasets:
1. To get Values of Performance counters form the test
2. To get Threshold values

In SSRS, I've passed Server name as parameter & created group on server name to get data of all server.

I've tried to capture test wise threshold using multilookup function.

[image]

but I'm not aware abount conditional split in ssrs.

Expected Result: 
Exchange & SQL oth are selected then,
for Exchange tablix it should show 1 & for SQL tablix it should show 2.

Actual Result:
Its showing 3 (2+1) in both tables.

Comment: Do you have a separate tablix for each dataset?

Comment: If you want a separate row for each Test, you just need to add a Grouping by Test Name, otherwise I'm not sure what you want - you already were able to put the (2, 1) in the Threshold column.

Comment: @WEI_DBA  I've 1 tablix & 2 different datasets. I'm using both datasets in one tablix.

Comment: @HannoverFist I'm able to get perf conters value using grouping function but while trying for threshold value it gives me sum of all tests instead of individuals while having multiple test. What I want is: while Excahnge & SQL is selectes in exchange table it should show 1 as threshold & in SQL table it should show 2.

Comment: So you want a separate table for each test? Then you'll want to create a **List** object, set the Dataset to the same as your table, Group By **Test**, and put your current table in it. The list will repeat the table for each test and keep the data separated.

Comment: I've done it its working for perf counters but don't know why its not working for Threshold. P.S. I've created 2 datasets. 1 for perf counters value & another is for Threshold. & Tablix assign Perfcounter data set to tablix.

Comment: @HannoverFist as far as my understanding, due to 2 different dataset used in 1 tablix, I've to use aggregate fromula =Sum(Fields!a.Value, "THRESHOLD")
Is there any way to create formula without sum function?

Comment: You might be able to use LookUpSet to lookup the fields based on the values of the table. You may get duplicates if your table has duplicates, though.
` =Join(LookupSet(Fields!Test.Value, Fields!Test.Value,Fields!Threshold.Value,"DataSet2"),", ")`

Comment: @HannoverFist... I've done the same thing using multilookup. Using this I'm able to get **SQL:2, Exchange:1** now trying to get required data using string manipulation. Let me know if other way is more suitable.

Comment: Achieved... used multilookup to get threshold for each test & then match parameter name (test name) in previously achieved list of threshold for each test & then using string manipulation function (Left, Right function) got the required threshold.